# How prop.getProperty("browser") present in initialization() will work?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, config, pageobjects

```
static WebDriver driver;
static Properties prop;

public TestBase(){
try {
prop=new properties();
FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("/users/Christain/Documents/workspace"+"/qa/config/config.properties");
prop.load(ip);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTruce();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static void initialization(){
String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");

if(browserName.equals("chrome")){
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/User/Christain/Downloads/chromedriver");
driver=new ChromeDriver();
}
else if(browserName.equals("FF")){
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/User/Christain/Dwonloads/geckodriver");
driver=new ForefoxDriver();
}
```

If `prop.load(ip)` present in `TestBase()`, then how `prop.getProperty("browser")` present in `initialization()` will work?

I mean `prop.load(ip)` know where config file is and it's **range not outside** `TestBase()`,
then how `prop.getProperty("browser")` present in `initialization()` will work?

Comment: From your question I assume that you think that the problem is the scope of the variable `ip`? That does not matter here. `prop` loads the values from that file in the constructor. But this *requires* that the constructor is called before that static `initialization` method, which is not what you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can work but it's really bad and should be fixed. This code requires that you create an instance of `TestBase`, and that act will initialize the *`static`* variable `prop`. This is valid java but idiotic: That means invoking `initialization()`, a static method, will throw a NullPointerException unless you invoke the constructor once. If you invoke the constructor more than once, it keeps re-loading that properties file for no good reason.

The exception handling is also deplorable (the proper "I do not want to deal with it" catch block is `throw new RuntimeException("uncaught", e)`, not `e.printStackTrace()`, and the catch of `FileNotFoundException` should be deleted, given that the `IOException` already deals with it; FNFEx is a subtype of IOEx).

In general `static` should be avoided, but if somehow its appropriate here (doubtful, but not enough context to be sure), such a setup should look like either:

```
class TestBase {
  private static final TestBase INSTANCE = new TestBase();
  private final Properties prop;

  private TestBase() {
    prop = new Properties();
    try {
      try (var ip = new FileInputStream("/users/Christain/Documents/workspace/qa/config/config.properties")) {
        prop.load(ip);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("uncaught", e);
    }
  }

  public static TestBase get() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }

  public void init() {
    String browserName = ....;
    .. code as written here ..
  }
}
```

and where you currently have `TestBase.initialization()`, you should have `TestBase.get().initialization()` instead.

Alternatively:

```
public class TestBase {
  private static Properties properties;

  private static void ensureProperties() {
    if (properties != null) return;
    Properties p = new Properties();
    try {
      try (var ip = new FileInputStream("/users/Christain/Documents/workspace/qa/config/config.properties")) {
        prop.load(ip);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("uncaught", e);
    }
    properties = p;
  }

  public static void initialization() {
    ensureProperties();
    String browserName = ....;
    ... code as written here ....
  }
}
```